# Erro ao mostrar o tempo passado de vários posts em PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, datetime

```
<?php
function timeAgo($time_ago){
$cur_time   = time();
$time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;
$seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
$minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
$hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
$days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
$weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
$months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
$years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
// Seconds
if($seconds <= 60){
    echo "$seconds segundos atrás";
}
//Minutes
else if($minutes <=60){
    if($minutes==1){
        echo "um minuto atrás";
    }
    else{
        echo "$minutes minutos atrás";
    }
}
//Hours
else if($hours <=24){
    if($hours==1){
        echo "uma hora atrás";
    }else{
        echo "$hours horas atrás";
    }
}
//Days
else if($days <= 7){
    if($days==1){
        echo "ontem";
    }else{
        echo "$days dias atrás";
    }
}
//Weeks
else if($weeks <= 4.3){
    if($weeks==1){
        echo "à uma semana";
    }else{
        echo "$weeks semanas atrás";
    }
}
//Months
else if($months <=12){
    if($months==1){
        echo "um mês atrás";
    }else{
        echo "$months meses atrás";
    }
}
//Years
else{
    if($years==1){
        echo "um ano atrás";
    }else{
        echo "$years anos atrás";
    }
}
}

?>
<?php
  $curenttime=$date_uploaded;
  $time_ago =strtotime($curenttime);
  echo timeAgo($time_ago);
?>
```

Sendo que `$date_upload` é igual a (dd-mm-aa hh:mm:ss) no banco de dados.

Esse é o código, quando eu puxo só um post ele funciona, mas quando puxo vários posts dá esse erro:

> **error: Cannot redeclare timeAgo() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\poster.php:520) in)**

Comment: Parece que no arquivo `poster.php` tem uma função com o mesmo nome desta que vc postou (`timeAgo`), mas também pode ser problema com a inclusão de arquivos via `include`. Tente mudar o nome desta função, e se estiver usando `include`, tente mudar pra `include_once`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro diz que existe duas ou mais vezes uma função com mesmo nome no seu arquivo ou na chamada de um include.

Para resolver o problema, sugiro que tenha pelo menos dois arquivos, um com o processamento normal do código e outro somente com funções um pequena biblioteca, dessa forma é evitada a colisão de nomes de função. Outra alternativa a partir do php5.3 é usar name espaces.

Existem algumas ferramentas que identificam duplicação de código e copy & paste como o [php mess dectector](http://phpmd.org/), também a ajuda na identificação dessas colisões.

[Exemplo - erro simulado.](http://ideone.com/K9oy2f)

[Exemplo - solução com namespaces.](http://ideone.com/TIlkbf)

Comment: conseguir rsolver muito obrigado criei um arquivo da função chamado data.php e depois dei um include no topo da pagina include ('data.php'); depois eu apenas fiz um echo na pagina <?php
  $curenttime=$date_uploaded;
  $time_ago =strtotime($curenttime);
  echo timeAgo($time_ago);
?>